# Setting ClickListener on Activity using CursorAdapter

Tags: android

EDIT:
i solved it:

```
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            }
        });
```

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I need to set a `itemClickListener` on `ListView` which content is set by CursorAdapter in normal `Activity` in my case it's `AppCompatActivity` and not `ListActivity`. I saw some examples but every of them was about ArrayAdapter or Activity was `ListActivity`

Here's `Java` code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_workout_list);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.workout_listview);

    try {
        SQLiteOpenHelper sqLiteOpenHelper = new TrainingDatabaseHelper(this);
        db = sqLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        cursor = db.query("WORKOUT",
                new String[]{"_id", "NAME"},
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                "NAME ASC");

        CursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.item_list,
                cursor,
                new String[]{"NAME"},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0);

        listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
...catching...
    }
}
```

Of course i set a `listView`, `cursor` etc

Answer (score 0):

Just set itemclicklistener on your listview

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
         Toast.makeText(SuggestionActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```